# get list of files Curl

Tags: c++, curl

I wanna download  *.txt files from server using curl, but unfortunately I can't understand how to do it, because I'm beginner in curl, I though to use recursive iterator from boost::filesystem, maybe you have any different ways to solve my problem? thank you)

Comment: you have all the urls in a text file?

Comment: I'm sorry don't understand your question, I'm connecting to my server and I need download on my computer all txt files on this server

Comment: But first you need to get a list of all files to iterate throught them, i think

Comment: yeah, i know but what setopt i should use to get it?

Answer (score 0):

`boost::filesystem` only works with file paths on the local machine, and UNC paths on a local network.  You cannot use it to iterate remote files over the Internet.

If the files are on an HTTP server, libCURL *cannot* iterate the files directly, as that capability is not part of the HTTP protocol. Your *only* hope is if the HTTP server provides an HTML file (or other format) containing the file listing when you request a URL for the actual directory that the files reside in.  However, for obvious security reasons, many HTTP servers disable this feature!  Most servers will instead redirect to a specific file, like `index.html`, `index.php`, `default.aspx`, etc.  But, if the HTTP server does allow to retreive a file listing, you would have to retrieve and parse that listing data manually in order to determine the URLs of the individual files, and then you can download them as needed.

If the files are on an FTP server, then that is more desirable, as directory listings are part of the FTP protocol, and libCURL can retrieve an FTP directory listing (make sure the requested URL ends with a backslash so libCURL knows a directory is being requested and not a specific file).  However, you are responsible for parsing the listing data, which can be in any format the FTP server decides to send (and there are MANY MANY listing formats used by various online FTP servers!).  Modern FTP servers support the FTP `MLSD` and `MLST` commands (as opposed to the original `LIST` command) to facilitate easier parsing of listing data, so you can try instructing libCURL to use those commands (via libCURL's [`CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST`](https://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST.html) option) if the FTP server supports those commands.  Or, if you are interested in only the file names and not the file details (like timestamps, sizes, etc), you can use the FTP `NLST` command instead (via libCURL's [`CURLOPT_DIRLISTONLY`](https://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/CURLOPT_DIRLISTONLY.html) option).